# CTP Installation Error. Install Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2016 CTP3.2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I get an error:

> To Continue, install Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2016
>   CTP3.2

during the installation of SQL 2016 CTP 3.2. From where I can download CLR Types for SQL Server 2016 CTP3.2?

Comment: Try to take steps from this answer https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/edb5c2a4-ea69-4440-b2a2-0d1f156b8263/clr-types-for-sql-server-2016-install-error?forum=SQLServer2016Preview

Comment: Also, the final release version of SQL Server 2016 is available for download today. Suggest getting a fresh copy of the final release instead of this "very old" (by pre-release standards) CTP3.2

Comment: Installing the final release, as @SQLmojoe recommended, is what solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this problem too. The solution for me was access this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all

Click Download and in the list, search ENU\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi and ReportViewer

Best regards!

Comment: Hi Fernando, welcome to SO. Link-only answers are discouraged because the link could become broken later. Could you explain a bit more how this solves the problem/what this download is exactly?